# Fetch Discord IDs

Tags: javascript, discord

How do i fetch the ids of peoples who are in a server be be specific, I have a list of IDs and i want to check if any of the users are in a given server if they are then i want to fetch all the ids which are in the list

Example:

`91287318123, 1282379128, 128923712912, 282139823197, 1282621921, 21832187312, 21832713412`
above is the list of IDs

and among those
`91287318123`, `128923712912` are the one who are in a server with id `1827392683`

So i want to return those ids as pings making it `<@id>, <@id>` and so on

I don exactly know what to do, minimum i know that its a loop

Comment: do you use discord.js or do you want to make the api request manually?

Comment: @Julian I use discord.js